# ¿Cómo creo una red de contenedores Docker cuyas IP estén en mi red local?

Tags: docker

Estoy tratando de instalar un servidor samba en una distribución de Ubuntu dentro de un contenedor Docker. A través de la IP predeterminada que establece Docker a los contenedores no me funciona, de hecho no puedo hacer ni un sencillo ping. Yo quisiera crear una red que estuviera dentro del juego de IPs de mi red local, que normalmente son 192.168.1.X. Lo he intentado de todas las formas posibles y no me ha funcionado. He probado a instalar un servidor apache para poder acceder desde un navegador directamente a este servidor a través de su correspondiente IP, pero no me lo reconoce.

El comando que uso es este:

> docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 --ip-range=192.168.1.0/24 --gateway=192.168.1.250 nombre_de_red

Cuando corro un contenedor asignándole esa red el sistema le asigna la IP 192.168.1.1, la cual es correcta ya que está dentro del rango de IPs de una red local, el asunto es que aunque tenga la IP correcta es como si no formara parte de la red local ya que es inaccesible.

Mi pregunta es si es posible que un contenedor docker emule un equipo más de mi red local de modo que pueda a través de su IP acceder a un servidor apache, mysql, samba, nginx o el que corresponda.